# Cron job scheduled, but not running rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake, rvm

I'm struggling trying to make a cron job run. Here is what I have:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/jose/work/Cronox/lib/tasks/rake wines:destroy_wines >> /home/jose/crontab_errors.txt
```

My task looks like this:

```
namespace :wines do
  desc "delete all wines"
  task :destroy_wines => :environment do |t|
    Wine.delete_all!
  end
end
```

If I use this command:
**tail -f /var/log/syslog**
I can see this:

```
(jose) CMD (cd /home/jose/work/Cronox/lib/tasks/rake wines:destroy_wines >> /home/jose/crontab_errors.txt)
```

Every minute, But it does nothing at all. I'm also using **rvm** Does that have anything to do with it?

One more thing: when executed manually the task works fine.

What am I missing,

please, please help me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't invoking rake, you're just changing to the directory. Try

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/jose/work/Cronox/ && rake wines:destroy_wines >> /home/jose/crontab_errors.txt
```

Comment: I tried the following: 
***/1 * * * * cd /home/jose/work/Cronox/lib/tasks && rake wines:destroy_wines > ~/cron_errors.log 2>&1**

It's stating to look good but, in the log I get this:
**/bin/sh: rake: not found**

Do you know what else is needed in this case?

Thanks in advance sir !

Comment: rake is not on your path. If you are using rvm, use `rvm rake`. Specify the ruby version number if you have multiple rubies installed.

Comment: Could you help me with the Syntax to specify the ruby version? because I do have multiple rubies. And I can't find an example :(
Thanks in advance Sir !

Comment: Well, I actually tried it this way: 

**cd /home/jose/work/Cronox/lib/tasks && rvm 1.8.7@mygemset rake wines:destroy_wines > ~/cron_fail.log 2>&1**

And now the error in the log is: **/bin/sh: rvm: not found**
I don't know what else to do. please help.

Comment: Sounds like rvm isn't on cron's path. In your shell, type `which rvm` and put that path on the rvm command in your crontab. Or add that path to your crontab (see http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

Comment: Jeff, looks like this did the Trick: (using which rvm output) 
**/1 * * * * cd /home/jose/work/Cronox/lib/tasks && /home/jose/.rvm/bin/rvm rake RAILS_ENV=development wines:destroy_wines > ~/err1.log 2>&1**

Now I have this other problem...

**rake aborted!
no such file to load -- bundler/setup...........**

Do you know what is possibly happening now? THANKS ! ! !

Answer (score 3):

I used something similar to Jeff's answer, but I had to invoke `bundle exec` to get the rake task to run properly, and to do that I had to use the `rvm do` command.  Full cronjob looks like this:

```
*/15 * * * * cd /path/to/rails/app && /path/to/rvm 1.9.3-p392 do bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production my:rake:task >> tasks.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 3):

I have created an example and this is the command line:

```
 /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/myusername/rails_apps/yourapplicationname && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake admin:update_folios --trace --silent >> log/error_updating_folios.log'
```

You can find the full guide here:

```
http://heridev.com.mx/ruby/how-to-create-a-cron-job-for-ruby-on-rails-application-in-a-server-wich-uses-cpanel/
```

Cheers!